# Check if string has any character from another string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to make sure my users passwords contain at least one, a-z, one A-Z, one 0-9 and one special character.

I thought the best way of doing this would be to set variables like this:

```
$lower_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$upper_list = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numbers_list = '0123456789';
$special_list = '!"£$%^&*(){}[]=-`¬¦\|/?.>,<#~\'@;:*-+';
```

Whats the function I need? Or is there a better way of doing it? I know I could use preg_match but I have no idea how to write the regex.

Comment: If it is PHP, I'd suggest doing `preg_match()` with the regex pattern as `/[\d[:lower:][:upper:][:punct:]]/`

Comment: check this link  http://www.cafewebmaster.com/check-password-strength-safety-php-and-regex

Comment: Yes duplicate agreed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help:

```
$pattern = "/^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).*$/";
```